# how to show sequential results inside textfield

Tags: jquery, textfield, sequential

dear all.I want to use only one textfield for different results. what should I do if I want after pressing a few times a checkbox or another checkbox the results will appear sequentially in the textfield.for example:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="see" value="a">
<input type="checkbox" id="saw" value="b">

<input type="text" id="field">
<input type="button" id="show">
```

then i do something like:

```
 1. click "see"
 2. click "show"
 3. click "see"
 4. click "show"
 5. click "saw"
 6. click "show"
 7. click "saw"
 8. click "show"
 9. click "see"
 10. click "show"
```

then show results after click show button at text field:

```
aaba..and so on if any additional
```

Comment: When you get `see` twice in a row, are you checking, unchecking, then rechecking it?

Comment: no i click show button to show result.if i want to rechecking then show result i must click the show button again.

Comment: ok, I think I got it with the show button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As simple as:

```
var values = "";
$('#see, #saw').click(function() {
  values += $(this).val();
});
$('#show').click(function() {
  $("#field").val(values);
});
```

to only allow the checked=true checkboxes just:

```
var values = "";
$('#see, #saw').click(function() {
 if($(this).is(':checked'))
    values += $(this).val();
});
$('#show').click(function() {
  $("#field").val(values);
});
```

***Edited:*** to add the functionality to the `Show Button`

[**See working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/UBvhx/)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
$('input:checkbox').click(function() {
  $('#field').val($('#field').val() + $(this).val());
});​
```

Here's a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7b4Ka/).

If you need a variant where you only record the clicks that create a checked state, just wrap the assignment in:

```
if( $(this).is(':checked') ) {...}
```